# How to create a new column in pandas iterating existing columns without getting this next error?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

i'm trying to create a new column, iterating existing ones, but I keep getting the same error,don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
    import pandas as pd

    data = pd.read_excel('AAPL.xlsx', sheet_name='Hoja1')
    data.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
    data1 = data.loc['2011-08-20':'2008-05-15']
    for i in range(len(data1)):
        if (data1.loc[i, 'high'] / data1.loc[i, 'open'] - 1) * 100 >= 0.07:
        data1['Upside 7%'] = "OK"
```

and what i get is : TypeError: cannot do index indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>

Comment: Probably your index is not an integer. Try using `iloc` instead of `loc`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your loop can be done in pandas

```
df['Upside 7%'] = 'Not OK'
df.loc[((df['high'] / df['open']) - 1) * 100 >= 0.07, 'Upside 7%'] = 'OK'
```